# Woocommerce include parent product in title of child product

Tags: woocommerce

I have a multiple grouped products with simple product options set up like this:

- Photograph Name (Parent Grouped Product):

  - 7" x 4" framed
  - 7" x 4" unframed

Is there a way to get the simple (child) product name to automatically suffix the parent product name when displayed in the cart.

Currently shows: "7" x 4" framed"

Want it to show: "Photograph Name - 7" x 4" framed"

I know the long way would be to input the data manually when creating the product. But that seems counter intuitive.

Any best practice / php snippets would be great thanks!

John

Answer (score 0):

This is odd because what you are asking is the deault in the theme I am using. I would like to remove the parent product name in the grouped product listing.

The code I have for the link in the grouped.php is:

```
<a href="' . get_permalink( $child_product['product']->id ) . '">' . $child_product['product']->post->post_title . '</a>
```

Is this what you have?

Bridie